# How can I vertical align a div within another div?

Tags: html, css

i put to div with two different content in a parent div and i want set vertical align first div with second div

sorry for bad language

```css
.title-pin {
  position: relative;
}
.pin-icon {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
  -moz-border-radius: 25px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
.star {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 50px;
}
.title-container {
  padding-left: 60px;
  width: 400px;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="title-pin">
  <div class="pin-icon">
    <span class="star">★</span>
  </div>
  <div class="title-container">
    <h3>This title is unstable. This title is unstable. This title is unstable.`enter code here`</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to vertically align an image inside div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-div)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your .pin-icon CSS. Hope this will help you.

```
.pin-icon {
  top:50%;
  margin-top:-25px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your css

```
.pin-icon {top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);}
```

Comment: This is the easiest solution.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.title-pin {
  position: relative;
}
.pin-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
  -moz-border-radius: 25px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.star {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 50px;
}
.title-container {
  padding-left: 30px;
  width: 400px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 24px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="title-pin">
  <div class="pin-icon">
    <span class="star">★</span>
  </div>
  <div class="title-container">
    <h3>This title is unstable. This title is unstable. This title is unstable.`enter code here`</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Many ways you can get this. In short I just add one line on your css class .pin-icon **top: 25%**

```css
.title-pin {
    position:relative;
}
.pin-icon {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color:#333;
    color:#fff;
    top:25%;

    
}
.star {
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 50px;
}
.title-container {
    padding-left: 60px;
    width:400px;
    font-size:24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="title-pin">
  <div class="pin-icon">
    <span class="star">★</span>
  </div>
  <div class="title-container">
    <h3>This title is unstable. This title is unstable. This title is unstable.`enter code here`</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks @Mostafa, but when text is more than 3 lines, it doesn't work propebly

Comment: opps I thought you have only this 3 lines :(

Answer (score 1):

You can simply achieve this with **Flexbox**.

Just add `display: flex` and `align-items: center` to your wrapper div, in your case the `.title-pin`.

Some advantages of using the `display: flex` property

- It doesn't play a role anymore how long your text in
  `.title-container` is gonna be.
- In principle, you also don't even need to set a specific height to the children elements, but I think in your case you want that the `.pin-icon` has always the same **height** and **width** so it's just fine to set both to **50px**.

```css
.title-pin {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.pin-icon {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
  margin: 0 20px;
}
.star {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 50px;
}
.title-container {
  width: 400px;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="title-pin">
  <div class="pin-icon">
    <span class="star">★</span>
  </div>
  <div class="title-container">
    <h3>This title is unstable. This title is unstable. This title is unstable.`enter code here`</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Using flexbox is the best way for these cases. But I prefer @DanielaDonna for the OP case, because it's annoying to use flexbox if you are not using a CSS preprocessor with some flex mixins including browser prefixes.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.title-pin {
  position: relative;
  display: block;      
  margin: auto;
}
.pin-icon {
 <!--remove relateive: absolute; -->
  width: 50px; <!-- add this -->
  margin-left: 55px; <!-- add this -->
  height: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
  -moz-border-radius: 25px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
.star {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 50px;
}
.title-container {
  padding-left: 60px;
  width: 400px;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="title-pin">
  <div class="pin-icon">
    <span class="star">★</span>
  </div>
  <div class="title-container">
    <h3>This title is unstable. This title is unstable. This title is unstable.`enter code here`</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

as long as the element has a `height`, this will center the element vertically.

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin: auto;
```

```css
.title-pin {
  position: relative;
}
.pin-icon {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
  -moz-border-radius: 25px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.star {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 50px;
}
.title-container {
  padding-left: 60px;
  width: 400px;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="title-pin">
  <div class="pin-icon">
    <span class="star">★</span>
  </div>
  <div class="title-container">
    <h3>This title is unstable. This title is unstable. This title is unstable.`enter code here`</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```